# Next.js TypeScript and Cloudflare Pages Functions

Tags: typescript, next.js, cloudflare

I have created a minimal Next.js app with TypeScript, and created a functions folder with the following API:

```
import { jsonResponse } from "../utils/jsonResponse";

export const onRequestGet: PagesFunction<{ FILES: KVNamespace }> = async ({ request, env }) => {
    return jsonResponse({
        time: new Date(),
    });
};
```

The `PagesFunction` type is copied from example images app: https://github.com/cloudflare/images.pages.dev/blob/main/functions/types.d.ts

`jsonResponse` utility function comes from the same example app.

When building on Cloudflare, and also verified locally with `npx wrangler pages dev ./out`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
<stdin>:3:25: error: Expected ";" but found ":"
    at failureErrorWithLog (/Users/martinnormark/.npm/_npx/8c55f4bc76fffd7b/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1475:15)
    at /Users/martinnormark/.npm/_npx/8c55f4bc76fffd7b/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1264:29
    at /Users/martinnormark/.npm/_npx/8c55f4bc76fffd7b/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:611:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (/Users/martinnormark/.npm/_npx/8c55f4bc76fffd7b/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:708:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (/Users/martinnormark/.npm/_npx/8c55f4bc76fffd7b/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:578:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23) {
  errors: [
    {
      detail: undefined,
      location: {
        column: 25,
        file: '<stdin>',
        length: 1,
        line: 3,
        lineText: 'export const onRequestGet: PagesFunction<{ FILES: KVNamespace }> = async ({ request, env }) => {',
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Expected ";" but found ":"'
    }
  ],
  warnings: []
}
```

If I remove `PagesFunction<>` and the parameters (which I don't use in this example) it works fine.

But this is just a minimal example, where I'm not using anything from the `EventContext`. I have APIs where I need to access KV namespaces via the `env.FILES` param.

For example this:

```
import { jsonResponse } from "../utils/jsonResponse";
import { Magic } from "@magic-sdk/admin";

// Initiating Magic instance for server-side methods
const magic = new Magic(process.env.MAGIC_SECRET_KEY);

export const onRequestPost = async (context: any) => {
    try {
        const req: Request = context.request;
        const didToken = req.headers.get("Authorization")?.substr(7);
        await magic.token.validate(didToken!);

        return jsonResponse({
            authenticated: true,
        });
    } catch (error: any) {
        return jsonResponse(
            { error: error.message },
            {
                status: 500,
            }
        );
    }
};
```

It turns out the type annotation `context: any` is not liked.

This seems to be related to the functions folder being tucked inside the Next.js app. I tried scaffolding a Vite app with React TS template and it works fine. Code for that here: https://github.com/martinnormark/reactts-cf-pages-functions

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you split the declaration and export into separate lines, do you still get the same error?

Comment: Yes, same error.